# how to reload simple_captcha image

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'd like to have a link under simple_captcha image. Click to link should reload simple_captcha image. I can't find in gem any information about it. How can I update it? Thanks for advance.

Comment: I tries to implement SimpleCaptchaController, but It looks like, action is catched in middleware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have also faced the same issue then after i find the solutionas mentioned below .
As i have  used  jquery  to refresh the captcha div this is the javascript code i have used to refresh the captcha .

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".refresh_image").click(function() {
    $('#captcha').load("/users/dashboard/refresh_captcha_div");
  });
});
```

After this put the view page codes for captcha in a partial file and render the partial everytime when the refresh div (any link or button) is clicked by the above codes pasted . It will call a action there you need to render the partial only . (here refresh_captcha_div in users/dashboard controller). below are the view files codes of mine for reference .

```
       <div id ="captcha">
         <%= render "simple_captcha_institute"%>
       </div>
         <%=link_to (image_tag "/assets/refresh_image.png"),"#", :class => "refresh_image"%>
```

This is the view page codes where i am rendering the partial and then the codes in the partial are

```
<div id="refresh_captcha">
  <%= show_simple_captcha(:object=>"institute", :label => "Type The Above Characters..") %>            
</div>
```

Comment: Nice solution works great, do you know if this simple captcha gem only works for the last generated key? its multi user compatible ( multiple users trying to get password at aprox same time would make this fail (?))